# Finding common ratio from two sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-theorem

I'm struggling with this very basic question on the binomial theorem:

> The sum of the first and second terms of a geometric progression is 12, and the sum of the third and fourth term is 48. Find the two possible values of the common ratio and the corresponding values of the first term.

So I tried approaching this in two ways. The first:

$$
u_1 + u_2 = a + ar = 12 \\
u_3 + u_4 = ar^2 + ar^3 = 48 \\
4a(1 + r) = ar^2 + ar^3 \\
4 + 4r = r^2 + r^3 \\
r^3 + r^2 - 4r - 4 =0
$$

Okay, no solution there. So then I tried:

$$
S_2 = \frac{a(r^2 - 1)}{r-1} = 12 \\
S_4 = \frac{a(r^4 - 1)}{r-1} = 48 \\
\frac{4a(r^2 - 1)}{r-1} = \frac{a(r^4 - 1)}{r-1} \\
4r^2 - 4 = r^4 - 1 \\
r^4 - 4r^2 + 3 =0
$$

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Look at your first two equations. Divide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your first two equations we get
$$\frac{48}{12}=\frac{ar^2+ar^3}{a+ar}=r^2.$$

Comment: Thanks. A follow-up is: Find also the least value of $n$ for which the sum of the first $n$ terms of this series differs from the sum to infinity by less than $10^{-5}$. Am I right in assuming: $S_{\infty} - S_n > 0.00001$, where $S_{\infty} = 1.6$?

Comment: It must be a different series, for both $r=2$ and $r=-2$ the series diverges (unless you interchanged the $48$ and $12$ in the question).

Comment: Sorry, yes. The first three terms of the geometric series are $2$, $-\frac{1}{2}$, $\frac{1}{8}$.

Comment: The sum of the first $n$ terms is $2\times\frac{1-(-1/4)^{n-1}}{5/4}$. The (absolute value of the difference  between this and the sum to infinity is, after simplification, $(8/5)(1/4)^{n-1}$. Now find the appropriate $n$.

Comment: Isn't the sum to the first $n$ terms given by $S_n = \frac{a(1 - r^n)}{1-r}$? Not $r^{n-1}$...

Comment: Yes, I slipped. Should not answer a question in a comment. We want to make $(8/5)(1/4)^n \lt 10^{-5}$.

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how to get there. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: The sum to infinity is $8/5$.  The sum of the first $n$ terms is $(8/5)(1-(-1/4)^n)$. The absolute value of the difference is $(8/5)(1/4)^n=1.6/4^n$. This is first less than $10^{-5}$ at $n=9$. (Fool around with calculator or use logarithms.)

Answer (score 1):

Continuing with the notation you've used, given $a + ar = 12$, $ar^2 +ar^3 = 48$, we see that

$ar^2 + ar^3 = r^2(a + ar)$

$\implies 48          = r^2*12$

$\implies r = \pm 2$

Back-substituting this gives us $r = 2$ and $a = 4$ or $r=-2$ and $a = -12$.